# Find circular imports in Python - automated

Tags: python, lint

Circular imports in Python can lead to suddenly appearing bugs.

I guess it should be quite easy to detect them automatically:

1. Import all code
2. Build a graph
3. Check for cycles.

Lazy imports which happen during run time are out of the scope of this question.

Does anybody know a tool which can detect circular imports in Python?

Comment: I was told pylint can do this. But a simple test failed. See https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/515/recursive-import-not-detected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pylint does it. But it is not obvious for pylint newbees, since you need to call pytlint with  both file names as argument.

See https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/515/recursive-import-not-detected